# Free & Open Backup utility alternative to Deja Dup for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, backup

I am looking for a gratis, non-proprietary and configurable backup utility with support for:

1) cloud upload/download of files and local backups/restore

2) ability to choose what files/folders to include/exclude

3) easy configuration

A gui interface is not necessary as I am fine with using the command-line. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: what features do you need? By "free and open" I assume you mean "gratis" (no payment required) and "open source"?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't had enough tea yet when I wrote this.

Comment: :) Should it be possible to retrieve "older backups" (think e.g. of a file twice overwritten/replaced) – or rather a "mirror" (just a copy of what you have locally)? And what kind of cloud would you trust with your data that you don't mention encryption at all?

Answer (score 0):

Like i posted about [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/linux-backup-and-replication-software/79451#79451), [BorgBackup](http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/) is a really neat option that offers deduplication of your backups so each subsequent backup only stores what has changed since the last backup, allowing you to store terabytes worth of backups.

This does have the downside where if a particluar file in the backup gets corrupted/lost, its is lost in every backup, but if you run a new backup containing that file, it can restore itself.

Its fairly command-line focused but their documentation is pretty thorough and there's explanations for how to do all sorts of things like start a backup when a drive is connected