# Linux/Ubuntu backup with incremental and smart retention

Tags: linux, backup, ubuntu

I've been looking for a backup solution for Linux/Ubuntu. I want to use incremental backup and smart retention/rotation to minimize disk usage. And I'd like a GUI.

I've tried out or looked at many programs including Bacula, Amanda, Timeshift, rsync, grsync, DejaDup, rdiff-backup, etc. Duplicity has great "smart retention" meaning it keeps a certain number of files per day, week, month and year, but there is no option for plain file copy backup except storing them inside a chunked/encrypted file system. Bacula is complex, even to get a GUI up (either installing a web server for baculum or using BAT). Timeshift only does system files, I couldnt get it to exclude them and the author sells his own for user files. rsnapshot looks good but doesnt have a GUI. There were a couple of limited GUI attempts.

I like the idea of using rsync as that is what Dropbox was built on, and it has a delta sync mode that only changes part of a large file, handy when backing up remote. LuckyBackup, DejaDup. grsync are good but dont have smart retention. There are some scripts for doing the retention.

Cobian Backup on Windows was good. I think the best option is [Backintime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime). It's a little annoying that it buries backups in nested directories, so I'm wondering if there's anything better.

There is a related question, but with less specific requirements. I think these reqs are something a lot of people want. Maybe this Question can be a central place for those searching with similar needs. [Linux backup and replication software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/linux-backup-and-replication-software)

Comment: If you can do without a GUI, [rsync-push-backup](https://github.com/SebKuzminsky/rsync-push-backup) would be a good option. I'm using it for years (and also have contributed to the project), it works pretty well. As the name suggests it's based on rsync (using hard links to minimize disk space needed) – and has smart retention: you can define how many hourly, daily, weekly and monthly backups you wish to keep – and for restore can access the proper directory directly.

Comment: @Izzy cool, thanks for the suggestion.. i'll check it out.

Comment: If it turns out to be an acceptable solution, let me know to make it an answer. I didn't right away as it not fully matches your requirements (no GUI) – though to my experience, this is a set-and-forget solution not needing any GUI ;)